# FB URL comments (fb:comments) implementation in iphone app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios4, fbconnect

Is it possible to implement FB URL comments (fb:comments) features on iphone app (using graph or fql API)? Possible solution requires that server side (some feed aggregator) needs to connect url to some FB account so that comments can be moderated and iphone app needs to have features to post a comment and get comments for specific url.
The app part is not a problem, I was able to post and get comments for url that is already connected to some account (got it from some web site that have fb comments implemented), but I need stome guideline how to progamaticaly on server side connect url to some account so I can post/get comments for it on client side.

Thx